# HTML fragment links work with CSS positioning?

Tags: html, css, url-fragment

Last night I decided to add HTML fragment links in my computer listing page. However, no matter the pattern of linking, or whichever browser I use, those fragment links are simply not navigatable.

http://icelava.net/mycomputers.aspx#SEPHIROTH

http://icelava.net/mycomputers.aspx#DIABLO

*UPDATE on Answer: the links now flow correctly to the fragment locations after my mistake with the tag attribute has been highlighted.*

I did not find any real answer, but from what I have read, there are hints to suggest that my use of CSS positioning to form the two-column layout with two DIVs may be giving the browser trouble in figuring the vertical location of the fragment links.

```
#ContentCol
{
   margin-right: 130px;
   padding: 3px;
}

#RightSideCol
{
   background-color: #fff;
   float: right;
   padding: 0px;
   width: 126px;
}
```

If that is the case, what would an appropriate approach be to allow HTML fragment links?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for those urls to navigate to your intended target, you need named anchors instead of the linked anchors that you have in your page. Example:

```
<a name="SEPHIROTH" />
```

(without the hashmark)
instead of:

```
<a href="#SEPHIROTH"> #1</a>
```

Preferably, instead of using named anchors, you could also just give the element that you want to navigate an `id` attribute.

```
<td id="SEPHIROTH">...</td>
```

Another example. Try this link: http://icelava.net/mycomputers.aspx#FooterBanner
You see, it scrolls down to your footer, because of the `id` attribute.

Comment: OH! i forgot.... href="#fragment" links to another position in the page with that fragment link. It does not specify the link location itself. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your code, you have, for example:

```
<a href="#SEPHIROTH">#3</a> Dell XPS M1530
```

You may want to add an `id` attribute:

```
<a id="SEPHIROTH" href="#SEPHIROTH">#3</a> Dell XPS M1530
```

When you click that `<a>`, it would 'jump' to itself.  Is this what you want?